# how to use mat-paginator as offset, limit data of mat-table

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

I use mat-table and mat-paginator of Angular material, but I have a problem about page-length, page-index and size of table data. Example I count data from sever is 100, and I must use HttpClient  data offset =  0 and limit = 10 query then I received 10 row first. so I want to show label range of mat-paginator: [1 - 10 of 100 <  >], and button [>] can click. I try to find answer alot but I can't. So any solution for my problem.

Note: I don't want search all data from server. its very slow my project and it's bad for thinking.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If i understood your question correctly this what you want

try this official link of material table https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples

and heading is **Table retrieving data through HTTP**

try the above one if you didn't understand let me know i will edit this

Comment: If it is usefull please accept the answer so that others can benefit